# Работа веб-камеры в opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Вот код:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24) # Частота кадров
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 600) # Ширина кадров в видеопотоке.
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480) # Высота кадров в видеопотоке.

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("camera", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27: # Клавиша Esc
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

У меня самая простая вебка, подключена через usb, в других приложениях показывает  изображение, вообщем всё хорошо работает. Когда запускаю код, программа ничего не выводит в терминале, даже не создается окно под названием "camera". Подскажите, что почему не выводит изображение вебки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй поменять цифры в строчке `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`.Возможно у тебя вебка весит на `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)` и так далее.