# Почему не передается изображение с камеры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

нужно сделать вывод изображения с веб-камеры, но почему то не срабатывает(в окне просто белый фон), в чем дело?

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
win = Tk()


win.geometry("700x350")

label =Label(win)
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def show_frames():
   cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)

   imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
   label.imgtk = imgtk
   label.configure(image=imgtk)

   label.after(20, show_frames)

show_frames()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: state, frame = cap.read() выведите print(state), возможно камера не возвращает фреймы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сначала с видео файлом, если работает значит камера не отдаёт фреймы.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label

import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.size_video = 0, 0

        self.__source = None
        self.frame_widget = None
        self.ui_elements()

    def ui_elements(self):
        self.frame_widget = Label(self)
        self.frame_widget.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def initialization_camera(self):
        self.__source = cv2.VideoCapture(r'video\input_video_file.mp4')
        result, frame = self.__source.read()
        opencv_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        height = opencv_image.shape[0]
        width = opencv_image.shape[1]

        self.size_video = width, height

    def show_frame(self):
        result, frame = self.__source.read()
        opencv_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = Image.fromarray(opencv_image)

        photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=frame)

        self.frame_widget.image = photo_image
        self.frame_widget.configure(image=photo_image)
        self.frame_widget.after(20, self.show_frame)

    def run(self):
        self.geometry(f"{self.size_video[0]}x{self.size_video[1]}")
        self.show_frame()
        self.mainloop()


def main():
    application = Application()
    application.initialization_camera()
    application.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Вот ещё подсказка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1349705/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-opencv-python